# foreach for array of objects in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array of object like this example:

```
[
    {"idroom":"3","idoption":"1","included":"0"},
    {"idroom":"3","idoption":"2","included":"0"},
    {"idroom":"3","idoption":"6","included":"1"},
    {"idroom":"3","idoption":"7","included":"1"},
    {"idroom":"3","idoption":"16","included":"0"},
    {"idroom":"3","idoption":"17","included":"0"}
]
```

but if I do a

```
foreach ($array_of_objects as $single) { 
    ... 
    fwrite( $single->idroom) 
}
```

I get an empty file... why?

**EDIT**

To obtain that array of objects, I started from `javascript` as follows:

```
var dataAssociates = {};
var associatesRecords = [];
dataAssociates = { "idroom": dataViewRooms.getItem(gridRooms.getSelectedRows()).roomId,
   "idoption": $(this).find('input[name="option_name"]').attr('id'), 
   "included": (
          $(this).find('input[name="enabled_default"]').prop('checked')
              ? '1' : '0')
};
associatesRecords.push(dataAssociates);
...
$.ajax({.... , 'element' : JSON.stringify(associatesRecords) ,... });
```

Comment: Do you really have an array, or do you have a json encoded string as you've shown?

Comment: Do you really do ` fwrite( $single->idroom)` because that doesn't work no

Comment: Looking at this, you may need to convert it from what might be a Javascript array of objects to something PHP can work with. More information is needed.

Comment: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/8OLOf)

Comment: You're missing an argument to `fwrite()`

Comment: This code does not compile.

Comment: that's not a php array. it's MAYBE a json string.

Comment: I was trying to write into file to var_dump the json objects array because I am trying to get each object to build an INSERT INTO string but it look like foreach ($array_of_objects as $single) doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured out myself right now... I had just to do:

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['element']));
foreach ($data as $single) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO .... VALUES ( $single->idroom, $single->idoption, $single->included )";
    ...
}
```

So it worked! 
Thanks to everyone anyway!!

Cheers! 
Luigi

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->idroom = "3";

$obj->idoption = "1";
$obj->included = "0";
$array_of_objects[] = $obj;

$obj->idoption = "2";
$obj->included = "0";
$array_of_objects[] = $obj;

$obj->idoption = "6";
$obj->included = "1";
$array_of_objects[] = $obj;

$obj->idoption = "7";
$obj->included = "1";
$array_of_objects[] = $obj;

$obj->idoption = "16";
$obj->included = "0";
$array_of_objects[] = $obj;

$obj->idoption = "17";
$obj->included = "0";
$array_of_objects[] = $obj;

$filename = 'test.txt';
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
 if (!$handle) {
     echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
     exit;
}

foreach ($array_of_objects as $single) {
    fwrite($handle, $single->idroom);
}
fclose($handle);
```